# JDBC Realm Login Page

Tags: java, jdbc, authentication, jdbcrealm

i tried to create a login page using JDBC realm but did not works.

My steps :

> 1. Create database, user and group table
> 2. Create connection pool and data source, custom realm.
> 3. Add security roles mapping, login constraint, security constraint and
>      security roles.
> 4. Create login jsp and login servlet

I can ping the connection pool during creation.

What is the minimal configuration require to perform the above task ?

My Code :

```
create table login
(
  username varchar(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT usernamePk primary key, 
  password varchar(128) NOT NULL 
);

insert into Login values('peterwkc', '1234');


create table grouptable
(
        username varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        groupid  varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT GROUP_PK PRIMARY KEY(username, groupid),
        CONSTRAINT USER_FK FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES Login (username)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/Login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>LoginConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>MyResource</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/LoginController</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>User</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Login</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/Error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/JDBC_Realm</context-root>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>User</role-name>
    <group-name>User</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    <principal-name>peterwkc</principal-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Login.jsp :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%--
    This file is an entry point for JavaServer Faces application.
--%>
<f:view>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1><h:outputText value="JavaServer Faces"/></h1>

      <form action="LoginController" method="POST" id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm">
        Username : <input type="text" name="username" /><p></p>
        Password : <input type="password" name="password" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>

      </form>

    </body>
  </html>
</f:view>
```

LoginController.java :

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoginController", urlPatterns = {"/LoginController"})
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    getServletConfig();
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }

  /** 
   * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
   * @param request servlet request
   * @param response servlet response
   * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
   * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
   */
  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
      /* TODO output your page here
      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet LoginController</title>");  
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      out.println("<h1>Servlet LoginController at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
       */
    } finally {      
      out.close();
    }
  }

  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
  /** 
   * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
   * @param request servlet request
   * @param response servlet response
   * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
   * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
   */
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
//        processRequest(request, response);
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {

      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      out = response.getWriter();


    } finally {
      out.close();
    }
  }

  /** 
   * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
   * @param request servlet request
   * @param response servlet response
   * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
   * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
   */
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
  }

  /** 
   * Returns a short description of the servlet.
   * @return a String containing servlet description
   */
  @Override
  public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
  }// </editor-fold>
}
```

I follow this tutorial. 
http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html

Questions : 
1. Why my code does not working ?

Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Any errors, log entries? Just to be sure: did you create the user groups? You can switch logging of GF security module to finest and search in the server.log for more information.

Comment: I do have group table. I have switch javax.enterprise.system.core.security to finest. Do i need provide coding for jdbc realm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed the tutorial, Glassfish expects to find MD5 hashes of the passwords in `usertable`. But you inserted `1234`. You will either have to insert the MD5 hash of `1234` which is: `81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055` or you could tell Glassfish to use plain passwords, but I don't know what to put in the `Digest` then.

HTH

**EDIT**

In the tutorial the realm name is `security` but in your web.xml it is named `Login`

**EDIT 2**

There is even more wrong: 
To use the automatic login mechanism of Glassfish the form in your Login.jsp should have `action="j_security_check"` and the names for user and password should be `j_username` and `j_password` respectively.

Also see  Matt Handy's answer and comment and provide some more details (such as error message or so). Otherwise it's very difficult to help if you just say "It doesn't work"

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any coding example would be great ?

Comment: see my update... I think you should follow this tutorial more precisely or use another one...

Comment: Can you provide a link with automatic login mechanism with form based authentication method ? Thanks.

Comment: I have successfully created and test the application but it when it does not redirect to another page when login successful.

Comment: It won't redirect you if you browse to the login page directly. If you browse to http://.../index.html and it is protected, then Glassfish will automatically redirect you to your login form. If the login was successful, then you will be redirected to index.html

Answer (score 1):

Configuring jdbc realm is a bit tricky. You gave a lot information in your question, but you missed to describe the error behavior.

Some ideas:

You have a group table, but does it contain the line (peterwkc, User)?

Did you store the hash of your password?

How does your JDBC realm configuration look like?

If you set the logging of the security module to finest, what's in *server.log*?

Comment: Yes, i don't have (peterwkc, user) in group table. I changed to store hash password. I got security roles mapping, login and security constraint. I have successfully created and test the application but it when it does not redirect to another page when login successful

Comment: What is the advantage of automatic login mechanism using glassfish compare to manual jdbc realm ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out as I've analytically answered your question (minor mistakes may be inside):
[JDBC Realm Form Authentication How To](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159341/jdbc-realm-form-authentication-how-to/6159653#6159653)