# How to use JPA with a simple permission system with users, groups and rights?

Tags: java, jquery, database, jpa, annotations

I would like to build a simple ORM/database permission system where I have users, groups and rights:

- Each user can be a member of multiple groups, every group can have multiple users as members.
- Each relationship between user and group has an additional piece of information: rights.

The idea is that each user can have different rights in each group.

How should my entities look like so I can query things

- from the "group view" like "retrieve all members of this group"
- and the "user view" like "retrieve all groups this user is a member in"
- as well as "given this user and this group, which rights does the user have"?

I'm using Java 6 with JPA2 annotations and EclipseLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to look at implementations already provided by the application server community. Typically speaking, what you've described is a definition of form based authentication.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/realm.html

Basically speaking, the relationship is:

```
    User
      + Role[]
```

Once configured this allows frameworks such as JSF (but you'll notice I'm accessing the Tomcat session here) to query for a specific role. The code below is taken from a basic form-based authentication scheme I have on a small web-app, and it is in dire need of refactoring, I've just had higher priorities

```
public boolean isUserInRole(Roles role)
  {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().isUserInRole(role.getRoleValue()); 
  }
```

In this case Roles is a (poorly named) enum type that is stored in my "Role" Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "user_user", "role" }))
public class Role implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
    private String role;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getRole()
    {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role)
    {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

This ends up creating the tables (as I specified the fields) so I can provide an SQL query to the configuration and create a realm. There's a lot of good documentation on this if you Google "j_security_check".

As to a group? A group sounds like a collection of roles to me--so it isn't a stretch to modify the query to a third table, or simply provide an enum.

(after reading this, the only clarification is that my roles are stored in an enum which contains the string value of the role, so roles.getValue() returns a string like "administrators".

Comment: I'm trying to gather basic experience. I pretty much know that everything imaginable has already been built. PS: Groups are not just a collection of roles. A group has users, each with different rights.

Comment: @soc I agree, the groups are not a collection of roles, however in an implementation of form-based authentication that might be the easiest way to implement it (thinking of a Linux group, you might have a group-writable folder--this could be a role or a collection of roles--this group has access to x...z). Thanks for the excellent comment.

Comment: @soc This might answer your question with more clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159341/jdbc-realm-form-authentication-how-to

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking

A User table
A Group table
A User_is_in_group link table

A Rights table.
A User_in_group_has_Rights table.

Then map all the links to the relevant fields in JPA.

I can do more detail, but maybe this is enough for you to create your entities, as it will also depend on what fields you want.

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate more detail.

Comment: Tables:
User {id, name}
Group {id, name}
Rights {id, name}

Join tables:
User_in_group {user_id, group_id}  //Rows only created when adding user to a group
User_in_Group_has_Rights{rights_id, user_in_group_id}  //Rows only created when assigning a 'user_in_group' some rights

From a database view that's what I was thinking.  
Mapping the first 3 tables to JPA should be no problem.  The next two I'm not sure how.  From here (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany
it looks like the two JOIN tables I'm advocating are created from the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a example with three tables (user, group and user_group):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private List<Grupo> groups; //-> a lot of rules and permissions

    public Usuario(){
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /** Here is the third table **/
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_group", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
                              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="group_id"))
    public List<Grupo> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<Grupo> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

//////////////////////

@Entity
@Table(name="group")
public class Group {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Grupo other = (Grupo) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```